# How does the function multinom from R package nnet compute the multinomial probability weights?

Tags: r, multinomial

I know the theoretical answer to the question of my title, which is discussed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression#As_a_set_of_independent_binary_regressions) or in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283595/fitted-values-for-multinom-in-r-coefficients-for-reference-category) previous question on Stack Overflow. My problem is that, even considering some numerical roundings, the  probability weights I compute using the coefficients fitted in the `R` function `multinom` are quite different from the weights directly obtained from the same function (through `predict(fit, newdata = dat, "probs")`). I tried to numerically compute these weights in `Java` and `R`, and in both implementations I obtain the same results, which are in fact different from the values returned from `predict`.

Do you know how I may discover the implementation of the function `predict(..., "probs")` for the `R` function `multinom`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first install `nnet` and open the help page for `nnet` function. I see that the function creates a `nnet` object.

I try`predict.nnet` but nothing comes up. This means either the package is not loaded, the function doesn't exist or it's hidden. `methods("predict")` reveals that the object is actually hidden (indicated by the `*`).

```
> methods("predict")
 [1] predict.ar*                predict.Arima*             predict.arima0*            predict.glm               
 [5] predict.HoltWinters*       predict.lm                 predict.loess*             predict.mlm               
 [9] predict.multinom*          predict.nls*               predict.nnet*              predict.poly              
[13] predict.ppr*               predict.prcomp*            predict.princomp*          predict.smooth.spline*    
[17] predict.smooth.spline.fit* predict.StructTS*
```

Calling this function explicitly reveals its code.

```
> nnet:::predict.nnet
function (object, newdata, type = c("raw", "class"), ...) 
{
    if (!inherits(object, "nnet")) 
        stop("object not of class \"nnet\"")
    type <- match.arg(type)
    if (missing(newdata)) 
        z <- fitted(object)
    else {
        if (inherits(object, "nnet.formula")) {
            newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata)
            rn <- row.names(newdata)
            Terms <- delete.response(object$terms)
            m <- model.frame(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.omit, 
                xlev = object$xlevels)
            if (!is.null(cl <- attr(Terms, "dataClasses"))) 
                .checkMFClasses(cl, m)
            keep <- match(row.names(m), rn)
            x <- model.matrix(Terms, m, contrasts = object$contrasts)
            xint <- match("(Intercept)", colnames(x), nomatch = 0L)
            if (xint > 0L) 
                x <- x[, -xint, drop = FALSE]
        }
        else {
            if (is.null(dim(newdata))) 
                dim(newdata) <- c(1L, length(newdata))
            x <- as.matrix(newdata)
            if (any(is.na(x))) 
                stop("missing values in 'x'")
            keep <- 1L:nrow(x)
            rn <- rownames(x)
        }
        ntr <- nrow(x)
        nout <- object$n[3L]
        .C(VR_set_net, as.integer(object$n), as.integer(object$nconn), 
            as.integer(object$conn), rep(0, length(object$wts)), 
            as.integer(object$nsunits), as.integer(0L), as.integer(object$softmax), 
            as.integer(object$censored))
        z <- matrix(NA, nrow(newdata), nout, dimnames = list(rn, 
            dimnames(object$fitted.values)[[2L]]))
        z[keep, ] <- matrix(.C(VR_nntest, as.integer(ntr), as.double(x), 
            tclass = double(ntr * nout), as.double(object$wts))$tclass, 
            ntr, nout)
        .C(VR_unset_net)
    }
    switch(type, raw = z, class = {
        if (is.null(object$lev)) stop("inappropriate fit for class")
        if (ncol(z) > 1L) object$lev[max.col(z)] else object$lev[1L + 
            (z > 0.5)]
    })
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000009305fd8>
<environment: namespace:nnet>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! :) Now I should "only" understand what this code means. :P

Comment: @Pippo As you can see, there's a lot of calling of `C` code. I suggest you go fetch the source from CRAN and dig further there.